# Penalizing outliers in a dataset

Tags: dataset, outliers

I have a dataset of ages ranked from smallest to highest. Next to each entry, I have calculated the respective ranked percentile. I then have to remove all values above the 99.5% percentile from the dataset (i.e. what we deem as outliers). Once these have been removed, I have to recalculate the ranked percentile values for the remaining entries, such that the new highest value has a percentile value of 1 (or 100%). For the outliers that were removed, I have to somehow penalize these values and then assign a percentile value based on the remaining data.

I have not come across any method in statistics of "penalizing" outliers, however, I have been asked to do this. Is there such a method of "penalizing" outliers in statistics, apart from removing the outliers completely?

Comment: Why do you deem those to be outliers?

Comment: Why do you have to remove what you call outliers? If they are correct, you're just throwing away information. Why would you? You haven't mentioned any reason that these values could cause any problem at all, were they handled just like all other observations. (Of course this is different oif some age values are, say, >200 or smaller than zero, but for finding this out you don't look at percentiles.

Comment: This is an old question, but all the talk of "have to" makes me think it was an assignment, and not a very good one!

Answer (score 2):

Penalizing part comes in the estimation portion. Robust Statistics is the field for this. [M-estimators](https://www.statisticshowto.com/m-estimator/) is an example of how the penalizing works or where it takes place. Basic idea is that it uses influence functions which measures the impact of each data point to the estimated  parameter statistics and adjustment is done accordingly.

An example that incorporates this approach can be done in R using the MASS::rlm()

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/354052)

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Thank you for the advice. I notice I was being very lazy and now I know how that impacts the quality of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well if we think of regularization, than high coefficients will be penalized. How do we get high coefficients, maybe through outliers which distort the mean impact of a variable.

One way I could think of, that the type of regression will automatically penalize for such a case, and that we have a regularization on the outlier. Maybe you start your search for regularization of outliers to get more info.

If you should really use weights to penalize your age, then you could define every age below the threshold with a w0=1 and all other values above that threshold  with a rising declining weight.

in market research when we try to get e represntative data set we do the same with some sorts of working class (we weight them up) so they represent a specific ratio of a speciic workerclass in the country, if we didn't get enough ppl in our dataset of that workerclass/proportion.

In summary: all i can think of is regularization of outliers. like for coefficients in lasso and ridge. But I have the feeling that would be done somehow automatically if the coefficient is pushed e.g. to zero, but I made no experiments on that. may be one of the other collagues here has a different insight.

Update:
This link however tells exactly, the same with regularization what i mentioned previously ago: maybe you have a look at it.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63900/how-regularization-helps-to-get-rid-of-outliers